# C++ Netbeans Sometimes Not Building

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I'm experiencing an odd issue with both Netbeans and Code::Blocks.
However, I am using Netbeans now, thence the title.

I sometimes experience problems in that I build my project, and run it, but when I execute it, it only seems to be the old code which is running.

In some occurrences, I have code which I have removed. When I re-build my project, the old code is the code which is compiled.

An example: I write a piece of object:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2f(..., ....);
glVertex2f(..., ....);
glVertex2f(..., ....);
glVertex2f(..., ....);
glEnd();
```

On some occurrences, when I remove this piece of code and build my project, this object still shows up in my executable.

It's like my project is sometimes not being build.. I even try building it multiple times.

I am using MingW.

Should anyone be so ... that they'd tell me that my code is wrong. It's JUST an example, so don't bother mentioning it!

I should also say now that sometimes when I am building, it doesn't detect any errors at all... But this seems to "randomly" occur. I can not find a link to this behavior.
Again, sometimes it builds fine - and the code it builds is actually compiled, and other times it says it has build my project but it hasn't at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why it happens but it's happened to me before too. Just use "Clean and rebuild". Most IDEs have this option.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That seems to work most of the time. I think this is an issue with MingW, as an oppose to the IDE I am using.